# How to have a hidden option in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to have a hidden option in dropdown so that user is unable to see it.
Following is the code :

```
<html:select property="stutype" style="text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #A5A5A5;" styleId="stutype" >
    <html:option value="ABC">ABC</html:option>
    <html:option value="DEF">DEF</html:option>
    <html:option value="XYZ"></html:option>
</html:select>
```

User shouldnt be able to see dropdown XYZ option in the dropdown. Mainly it should be hidden.This is because in the backend I'm changing one of the options to this value and proceeding.Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you need a hidden option for that, as opposed to not having the option in the first place? Anyway, add the `hidden` attribute to the option.

Comment: I guess you could apply visibility logic using style, specifically display attribute with a 'none' value. Better yet, use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be setting the `hidden` attribute. for the particular option.

```
<html:select property="stutype" style="text-transform: uppercase;background-color: #A5A5A5;"styleId="stutype" >
                    <html:option value="ABC">ABC</html:option>
                    <html:option value="DEF">DEF</html:option>
                    <html:option hidden value="XYZ"></html:option>
</html:select>
```

Comment: In that case go with option hidden like this  <html:option 
hidden value="DEF">DEF</html:option>